# Adobe Analytics API - Get real total for a metric

Tags: api, adobe, analytics, reporting, adobe-analytics

I'm having some troubles triying to get the total from the metric using the reporting API. The node total doesn't match with the total showed in the dashboard, but the individual nodes for each page match (but as I read you can't sum each node to get the total https://helpx.adobe.com/analytics/kb/sum-line-items-different-from-total.html)

Someone has any idea or something that could help me? Thanks!

**Dashboard:**

[image: i.imgur.com/dKmxuyb.png]

**API Json Result:**

[image: i.imgur.com/zez2J1Y.png]

Comment: that difference is huge.. it makes me think maybe you are doing one or more of the following: a) applying a filter and/or segment to the dashboard report, b) not using the same date range, c) not comparing apples to apples (looking at the same dimension and/or metrics)

Comment: Well, the Json that I'm using to generate the report it's obtained from the bookmark of that report (using bookmark/get report description), with the same date range and the funny thing it's all the individual items match (a good clue that I'm getting the same metric) but just the total doesn't match

Comment: okay, well over the years I have noticed that what Adobe uses for the interface doesn't always line up with what you do with the API. I've noticed a lot of stuff the interface that you can't do in the API, or else have to do it differently.